# lucene vs solr scoring

Tags: comparison, lucene, solr, scoring

Can some one explain (or quote a reference) to compare the scoring mechanism used by SOLR and LUCENE in simpler words.
Is there any difference in them;

I am not that good at solr/lucene but my finding showed as if they are different.

P.S: i just tries a simple query like "+Contents:risk" and didn't use any filter other stuff.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Lucene uses concepts from the [Vector space model](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_space_model) to compute the score of documents. In summary, queries and documents can be seen as vectors. To compute the score of a document for a particular query, Lucene calculates how near each document's vector are from the query's vector. The more a document is near the query in VSM, the higher the score. You can have more details by looking at Lucene's [Similarity](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/all/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html) class and Lucene's [Scoring](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/scoring.html) document.

Answer (score 5):

The actual formula can be found in the [Similarity javadocs](http://lucene.apache.org/java/3_0_2/api/core/org/apache/lucene/search/Similarity.html).

[Here's](http://www.lucenetutorial.com/advanced-topics/scoring.html) a summary of the parameters involved and a brief description of what they mean.

Solr uses Lucene under the hood, and by default [Solr uses the default Lucene similarity algorithm](http://wiki.apache.org/solr/SchemaXml#Similarity).